# Matlab: Delete box on annotation textbox, or creating a multiple line annotation text without box

Tags: matlab

I am writing the equation of a plane in an annotation of my 3D plot. I do not need a box, but since the only option that I have found has a box, is it possible to delete it?

```
str = {'z=a+bx+cy','a=0.2','b=1.2','c=0.3'};
annH = annotation('textbox',[0.8 0.9 0.08 0.08],'string',str)
```

I tried to get the list of the property of annH with set(annH) but I do not see anything as 'box','off' or similar.
Thanks
A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pair property-value you are interested is:

```
annotation(..., 'EdgeColor','none')
```

You can use [`inspect(handle)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/inspect.html) to have an interactive GUI to play around with any object's properties.

Answer (score 2):

another option instead of annotation is `text` ...

Comment: nope in 3D it wants x,y,z, not the coordinates of the figure.